# Retrofit skips init { } block of a data class while initializing

Tags: object, kotlin, initialization, retrofit, pojo

I'm going to set variables in class `Data` based on the arguments of `DClass`

```
abstract class Data(p: String) {
    var a1: String
    var a2: String

    init {
        """(\w+)(\d+)""".toRegex().find(p)!!.groupValues.run {
            a1 = "a1 is ${get(1)}"
            a2 = "a2 is ${get(2)}"
        }
    }
}

data class DClass(val p1: String, val p2: String) : Data(p1)
```

Then I'm able to get values of `a1` and `a2` after `DClass` is created:

```
DClass("string1", "string2").run { println("$a1 $a2") }
```

it returns "a1 is `string` a2 is `1`" as it should

Next I'm trying to make retrofit initialize DClass from the proper JSON response:
`@GET("loadDClass") suspend fun dClass(): DClass`

and say the program to do the same output of `a1` and `a2`, it just returns:

"a1 is `null` a2 is `null`".

So I found out that `init{}` block of `Data` is skipped as the retrofit just builds `DClass` but doesn't do the initialization

Is it possible to make abstract class' variables be initialized without doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

The `init` block is not called because `GsonConverterFactory` (which I assume you use since it is very common in this case) constructs the `DClass` in a special way that does not invoke its constructor. In particular, an internal class called [UnsafeAllocator](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/9d44cbc19a73b45971c4ecb33c8d34d673afa210/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java) is used. The JavaDoc for that class states:

```
/**
 * Do sneaky things to allocate objects without invoking their constructors.
 * [...]
 */
```

You could write your own Retrofit `Converter.Factory` but that would IMO be overkill. I suggest you add a simple member function to `DClass` instead of inheriting from `Data`, and also remove the `abstract` keyword from `Data`. `DClass` should look like this:

```
data class DClass(val p1: String, val p2: String)
    fun newData(): Data = Data(p1)
}
```

then you can construct a `Data` instance from the `body()` of the response:

```
call.execute().body()?.newData()?.run { println("$a1 $a2") }
```